# Chrome not adding headers in ajax requests from iframe, Firefox ok

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I've got a situation where I'm sending ajax requests from iframe, to same domain as original page, this Iframe loaded from same domain. Say, original page address is http://server/client and iframe src is http://server/client/addin1/view.html

From Iframe I make initial xhr request to api: POST http://server/api/connect which returns 201 with token in response header and a cookie.
Now I make next call to different api method, say, GET http://server/api/status, but in this case I add the token header, and I assume the received cookie will be included by browser - it's HttpOnly, my xhr has withCredentials: true.

The magic is: in FF it works ok, both token and cookie are set and sent, in chrome the token header is not added and cookie is not sent. I've verified that in both cases xhr.setRequestHeader(...) gets called, and just to be 100% sure I've verified with wireshark what gets actually sent.

Any idea why chrome, behaves differently from FF? Maybe I'm missing sth simple.

thanks,
Łukasz

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi, not actually not, but now I've gone through the issue again, and it turns out, it still doesn't work ok on my computer but it works ok with chrome on 2 other computers (same chrome versions)... So no clue still, but probably not  chrome issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to yours and  I was able to fix my CORS issue following this MDN article [CORS (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), see the section on *Requests with credentials*. There you'll find that you have to set the xhr options `withCredentials`. Here's the example they use:

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://bar.other/resources/credentialed-content/';

function callOtherDomain(){
  if(invocation) {
    invocation.open('GET', url, true);
    invocation.withCredentials = true;
    invocation.onreadystatechange = handler; // Needs to be implemented
    invocation.send(); 
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice but that's not that (double checked the flag is set). Again, it is sth with chrome *on my computer only*, cause FF works ok and chrome on other computers also works ok.